# Configure pulseaudio connections to persist with jackd

Tags: pulseaudio, jack

At present I have pulseaudio configured with the jack sink and source modules:

```
load-module module-jack-sink 
load-module module-jack-source
```

I've recently discovered that the first capture input on my audio capture card is a little faulty, which has caused me to move to the second capture.

Although this is problem is likely very uncommon, Discord seems to have problems with this arrangement. At present when in a VC normally, there's no issue. However when watching someone's stream, I'm unable to be heard.

After opening QjackCtl, and navigating to the connection graph, I could see that capture_1 is mapped to front-left, and capture_2 is mapped to front-right. I can manually connect capture_2 to front-left, which solves my discord issue, but I'm wondering if there is a way to have this persist, since a `pulseaudio -k` would revert it back to the default connections.

What would I need to configure, in order to have capture_2 mapped to both front-left and front-right on pulseaudio startup?

Comment: See if `load-module module-jack-source channel_map=front-left,front-left` does what you need

Comment: I've just tested that, but seems that the source is no longer available when viewed from the QjackCtl graph. I did try swapping the mappings, using what you used as an example, `load-module module-jack-source channel_map=front-right,front-left` which does resolve the mapping. Obviously, it be nice to be able to map both inputs to both sources, but I'll at least be able to work with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an option to module-jack-source to prevent default connections

```
    load-module module-jack-source connect=no
```

2. use these 2 commands to connect capture_2 to both channels of Pulseaudio JACK source

```
    jack_connect system:capture_2 Pulseaudio\ Jack\ Source:front-left
    jack_connect system:capture_2 Pulseaudio\ Jack\ Source:front-right
```